# Why XAML defined animation causes System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, doubleanimation

I need define simple animation in the XAML (without code behind), that must rotate the background image of button by changing the bounded boolean property. I have a button in the XAML:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" />
```

In the *Resources* section of the Window I create following:

```
<RotateTransform Angle="180" x:Key="rotAt180" />

<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="Images\pic.png" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolProp}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="{StaticResource rotAt180}" />
            <!-- This animation works good -->
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="180" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <!-- This animation causes exception -->
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions> 
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

*MyBoolProp* is initialized by True.
The first animation is works perfect. But the second animation causes  System.InvalidOperationException in PresentationFramework.dll (*"Unable to resolve all property references in the "RenderTransform.Angle" property path. Check that the corresponding objects support such properties"*).

I tried to move the second animation into the trigger, where *MyBoolProp* is True:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolProp}" Value="True">
 <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
     <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
             <DoubleAnimation From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" />
          </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

But the result is the same. What is wrong in such realization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RenderTransform must be set in the Style, not in the DataTrigger:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="Images\pic.png" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="{StaticResource rotAt180}"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolProp}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="180" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```